# What does "unilateral" mean in maths?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

From Fundamentals of Convex Analysis by Lemerechal and Hiriart-Urrut:

"polarity generalizes orthogonality in a unilateral way"

"convex analysis is the unilateral realm of inequalities, in contrast with linear analysis"

"Moving to the unilateral world of convex analysis, we replace linear hulls by conical hulls, and equalities by inequalities"

The book has mentioned this a couple times and it feels like some deep point about convex analysis but he has never actually explained what "unilateral" means.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess that it was a broad observation rather that any deep truth. For example, $A,B$ are orthogonal if $a^Tb = 0$ for all $a\in A, b \in B$ where as $A$ is contained in the polar of $B$ if $a^Tb \le 0$ for all $a\in A, b \in B$. One can view $a=b$ as bilateral in the sense that $a \le b$ abd $a \ge b$.

Comment: The statement is a little glib in the contrast of convex and linear analysis. In a linear space $L$, if $x \in L$ then $t x \in L$ for all $t$, whereas in a cone $K$, if $x \in K$ we can only assert that $tx \in K$ for $t >0$ (maybe $t \ge 0$ depending on your preferences). Again, the change is from the bilateral  $t \le 0$ or $t \ge 0$ to the unilateral $t \ge 0$.

Comment: Typically, *unilateral* means restricted to one side (fixed, but not specified) in a situation where it makes sense to have two sides, such as left limit and right limit for functions defined on the real line or upper half plane and lower half plane in the complex plane, and *bilateral* means the analogous situation when the restriction to a single side is removed (or the assumption of a single side is not made). In the examples you gave, it sounds like the "two sides" are the two sides of a hyperplane or the interior/exterior of a convex set.